# How to "delivery" message to php script from another server?

Tags: php

I have one php server where is public website. When somebody submit a form on this website I need to read data from the form on another php server.
This second server has no public ip address.

The only method I thought is saving form data to database and make a cron on the second server which will ask database about new rows.

There are two problems:

1) delay - cron will run once a minute (although there is a method to run a cron more times in a minute)

2) database load - asking 5 times a minute may not be good for performance

Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

Send form details to 2nd server with cURL?

When someone sends a form perform a GET request (or post) on 2nd server IP and have the server log the data there.

Comment: There is no public IP on the 2nd server. Thats the problem. :/